# ASP.NET Core project templates are missing Models folder if project is created with Windows Authentication mode selected

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

On our Windows 8.1 machine when we create an ASP.NET Core project using any of the two templates `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)` or`ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)` and select authentication mode as `Windows Authentication` the Models folder does not get created as shown in the image below. Whereas, if we use the default authentication `Individual User Account` the Models folder gets created. Why ASP.NET Core projects does not create Models folder when using Windows Authentication? I checked on the explorer view of the project, as well, and no such folder is there.

**No Models folder**:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to configure IIS to handle Windows Authentication and not your application...

Comment: @Pawel But how about adding Model classes etc.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem? What version of to ASP.NET Core tooling were you running? If you can reproduce this with the latest tooling contact me.  You can always add the Models folder yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have chosen **NO AUTHENTICATION** while creating your project. Change **NO AUTHENTICATION** to **INDIVIDUAL USER ACCOUNT**.

See this article
[Why doesn’t MODELS folder gets created automatically in solution explorer while creating new project in MVC 5 or ASP.NET Core 1.0?](http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/mvc-articles/models-folder-does-not-created-in-asp-net-mvc-core-1-0/)

Comment: But I've selected `Windows Authentication` and not `No Authentication`.